# How to mock rest client inside a Spring boot integration test

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, resttemplate, wiremock

In a spring boot integration test annotated with `@SpringBootTest` and ran with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` I can drop real http post calls to my rest controller via `@Autowired TestRestTemplate restTemplate` and `restTemplate.postForEntity(...)`

This works fine, just at the end of the controller -> service -> restclient chain I have a rest client bean, which is calling a 3rd party rest endpoint using RestTemplates inside, so I have to mock this endpoint. I found this lib `com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock`, which can be used for this, but was wondering whether there is not a nice spring boot way like for example the way to test a rest client with `@RestClientTest`to achieve this. I tried to mock the `MockRestServiceServer` so that I can write `expectations and responses` on it, but it does not seem to get it. The rest templates inside my rest client are always created as real, thus my call to the 3rd party endpoint fails.

Comment: You could use `@MockBean` (see e.g. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans) for the `RestTemplate`, but I think wiremock is a more appropriate level of abstraction, more resilient to refactors of how you call those endpoints.

Comment: @MockBean on a rest template does not work as well. It just does not mock the templates inside the rest client bean

Comment: Another way, you can use Spy for the service and mock only rest calls. Sometimes for this purpose in the service i create method for example: `public Client getRestClient()` , which i use for future spying.

Comment: Ok, maybe a possible way, but this looks to me like a hack, not really a prepared spring boot solution. In such a case I would rather go for wiremock

Comment: Just use the @MockBean for the RestClient instead of the RestTemplate?!

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the mock in the `@Before` using [ReflectionTestUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html)

```
@Inject
private Service service;

@Mock
private RestClient restClient;

@Before
public void setup() {
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "restClient", restClient);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but reflection does not seem to be a no-hack solution. Maybe there is just no spring boot way, they can improve this

Comment: You can also create and use a setter, if you don't like the reflection.

Comment: Thanks, actually I am after a good design, not just a possibility. Adding a setter just for the sake of testing is not really desirable.